# .htaccess rewriting www to http:// only and allowing HTTPS too

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rule in my .htaccess
It worked fine while I used only HTTP version.
But now I need HTTPS too.
Right now i'm always redirected to http version of my web.

I need:

If its https i need only execute last rule (last line)
If its http i need execute these three lines

```
            RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L,NE]
```

Can you please suggest changes into my .htaccess file?

Comment: what are you hoping to accomplish with your htaccess? We could probably give tighter code if we knew...

Comment: I want to add possibility to access my web through HTTPS. This .htaccess rules which I am using right now always redirect me to http:// domain.com

Comment: Don't forget to check if your SSL certificate is issued to www.domain.com rather than domain.com (or vice-versa). You don't want to be redirecting to the wrong domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^((?!www/).*)$ /www/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I'm still redirected to http version of my web when i try to access https

Comment: Depending on the server configuration, %{HTTPS} might give something other than 'on', such as '1'. You may have to do some research on this.

Comment: Assuming the OP wants to _also_ do this for http:, will this still work or will a separate set of rewrites be needed for http://www.domain.com?

Comment: @kolacek: Try this for a different browser.